# Bootstrap styles are applying to everything but radio buttons

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am practicing handling forms with Angular, and I like to use bootstrap to make things look pretty. For some reason, the bootstrap styles are applying to the rest of the form, but only the radio buttons are showing up with the default HTML styling.

[Screenshot of browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQSsd.png)

I have already tried to mess around with where I put the class name, changing how the inputs are wrapped, but nothing is working. I should mention that I'm following a tutorial online and my code matches the instructor's exactly. Yet his show up with the pretty bootstrap blue and white, and mine stay HTML grey and black. I want to fix this so it shows up blue and white, please refrain from answers telling me that it's "supposed" to be grey and black.

HTML

```html
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
        <div
          id="user-data"
          ngModelGroup="userData"
        #userData="ngModelGroup">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="username"
              class="form-control"
              ngModel
              name="username"
            required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Mail</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              class="form-control"
              ngModel
              name="email"
              required
              #email = "ngModel"
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <label>
            <input
              class="radio"
              type="radio"
              name="gender"
              ngModel
              [value]="gender">
            {{gender}}
          </label>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
          [disabled]="!f.valid"
        >Submit</button>
      </form>
```

TypeScript

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm;
  defaultValue = 'teacher';
  answer = '';
  genders = ['male', 'female'];
}
```

Comment: The radio buttons are correct please see this w3schools example https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_radio&stacked=h

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but that is incorrect. With my past projects, they have worked properly displaying the blue and white styling. It is only in this project that they are displaying this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom radio button

[Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Example copied from above link

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
 left: 9px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, you're right... Foot in mouth moment for me. Turns out the instructor was using a different browser and OS, which explains the default difference. Thanks for being patient!